# What does the MSP in STM32CubeMX HAL_xxx_MspInit() functions stand for?

Tags: c, embedded, driver, firmware

I was wondering what the abbreviation "MSP" in `HAL_xxx_MspInit()` callbacks stands for. I have seen that in some firmware drivers like the HAL library from ST.
For example:

```
void HAL_UART_MspInit(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart);
void HAL_SPI_MspInit(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi);
```

from `stm32f3xx_hal_uart.h` and `stm32f3xx_hal_spi.h`. I am wondering what `Msp` refers to. Is it just a naming convention for callbacks from `init` functions in drivers or does it have a deeper meaning (what I suspect it has).

Comment: Wouldn't the ST forum be the appropriate place to ask for **their** naming convention?(Don't use that rubbish STLib anyway, it is clumsy, inflexible and bloats your code without any actual benefit.)

Comment: I am not using it extensively. Only to quickly get some things running on my devboard. The reason I am asking SO is that I belief I have seen it from other vendors as well. I am mainly wondering if there is any reason in adopting such a convention for my own driver developments.

Comment: As a personal note: The STlib naming convention is - well - uncommon. Typically names starting with all-uppercase are macros and `enum-constants only. So, no, you should not adopt it, And that is nothing specific.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question.

Comment: Strictly speaking they are not *callbacks* - they are called directly and fully resolved at build-time rather than being called through a pointer assigned at runtime.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In STM32CubeMX it stands for ***M***CU **S**upport **P**ackage.

The STM32CubeMX documentation *["STM32CubeMX for STM32 configuration and initialization C code generation"](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/user_manual/10/c5/1a/43/3a/70/43/7d/DM00104712.pdf/files/DM00104712.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00104712.pdf)* (UM1718) is clear on this - section 5.1:

[image]

It does however somewhat unhelpfully use the term several times in the documentation before it actually defines it!

Other aspects of the STM32CubeMX naming conventions are also defined in this document.