STM32F411CEU6 program halts when switching system clock to PLL
I am trying to achieve high clock speeds on my STM32F411CEU6 board (96 MHZ) by tweaking the PLL clock without HAL. I have set the PLL clock source to HSE (25 MHz). My code halts whenever my debugger reaches this line:
setBits(RCC->CFGR, RCC_CFGR_SW, RCC_CFGR_SW_PLL);
halt((RCC->CFGR & RCC_CFGR_SWS) != RCC_CFGR_SWS_PLL);

I cannot figure out why. I have set the flash latency to the absolute maximum hoping it would help, since it did not work when I set it to 3WS (>90 MHz, 3.3V).
Implementation:

Macros:

inline void spin (volatile u32 pCount)
{
    while (pCount--) asm("nop");
}
#define halt(cond) while (cond) { spin(1); }

#define setBits(x, msk, v) x = ((x) & ~((u32)(msk))) | (u32)(v)
#define clearBits(x, msk) x = ((x) & ~(u32)(msk))


Init function:

void fhInit()
{
    fhInitPower();
    fhMspInit();
    fhHseInit();
    fhPllInit();
    fhCpuClockInit();

    systickInit();
}


Functions:

void fhMspInit()
{
    setBits(FLASH->ACR, FLASH_ACR_ICEN | FLASH_ACR_DCEN | FLASH_ACR_PRFTEN | FLASH_ACR_LATENCY, FLASH_ACR_ICEN | FLASH_ACR_DCEN | FLASH_ACR_PRFTEN | FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_7WS);
}

void fhHseInit()
{
    setBits(RCC->CR, RCC_CR_HSEON, RCC_CR_HSEON);
    halt(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_HSERDY == 0);
}

void fhPllDisable()
{
    setBits(RCC->CR, RCC_CR_PLLON, 0);
    halt(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLLRDY);
}

void fhPllEnable()
{
    setBits(RCC->CR, RCC_CR_PLLON, 1);
    halt(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLLRDY == 0);
}

void fhPllInit()
{
    fhPllDisable();

    auto m = 25;
    auto n = 192;
    auto p = 2;
    auto q = 4;

    auto pllReg = RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLSRC_HSE;
    pllReg |= m << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM_Pos;
    pllReg |= n << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN_Pos;
    pllReg |= (p >> 1) - 1 << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLP_Pos;
    pllReg |= q <<  RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLQ_Pos;

    setBits(RCC->PLLCFGR, RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLSRC | RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM | RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN | RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLP | RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLQ, pllReg);

    fhPllEnable();
}

void fhInitPower()
{
    RCC->APB1ENR |= RCC_APB1ENR_PWREN;
    setBits(PWR->CR, PWR_CR_VOS, 0b11 << PWR_CR_VOS_Pos);
}

void fhUpdateCoreClock()
{
    u32 pllm = RCC->PLLCFGR & RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM;
    u32 pllvco = (uint64_t)HSE_VALUE * (uint64_t)((RCC->PLLCFGR & RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN) >> RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN_Pos) / (uint64_t)pllm;
    u32 pllp = (((RCC->PLLCFGR & RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLP) >> RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLP_Pos) + 1U) * 2U;
    u32 sysCfkFreq = pllvco / pllp;
    SystemCoreClock = sysCfkFreq >> AHBPrescTable[(RCC->CFGR & RCC_CFGR_HPRE) >> RCC_CFGR_HPRE_Pos];
}

void fhCpuClockInit()
{
    fhPllEnable();

    setBits(RCC->CFGR, RCC_CFGR_PPRE1 | RCC_CFGR_PPRE2 | RCC_CFGR_HPRE, RCC_CFGR_PPRE2_DIV1 | RCC_CFGR_PPRE1_DIV2 | RCC_CFGR_HPRE_DIV1);

    setBits(RCC->CFGR, RCC_CFGR_SW, RCC_CFGR_SW_PLL);
    halt((RCC->CFGR & RCC_CFGR_SWS) != RCC_CFGR_SWS_PLL);

    fhUpdateCoreClock();
}

This clock configuration works perfectly in the Cube IDE when using HAL, so it is not a hardware problem.
Clock diagram:

Here is the github repo containing the whole project
I tried to find people with similar problems, but did not found anyone having this exact issue. Everybody's system clock just seems to switch to PLL without problem.

I can't see anything immediately wrong.  What is the state of the processor?  Is it spinning in your tight loop or genuinely halted?

One minor mistake is all those auto values end up with signed type, which can produce undefined behaviour if you shift a bit into the MSB position.  It will probably work fine, but is it really too much work to type uint32_t?

Your setBits macro is suspicious.  It does not do what it's name suggests and is not the inverse of clearBits as one might expect from the name.  It sets the mask bits to the value v - so it can both set and clear bits.  It is a dangerously misleading macro, and possibly contributing to your issue if perhaps you have mislead yourself.

"I have set the flash latency to the absolute maximum"   -  rather than tell us that, why not include the code?  We must assume perhaps that you did that before setting the PLL and switching to HSE?

The usual culprit when trying to reach higher clock speeds is incorrect flash wait state settings.

Also, you can many undefined behavior bugs caused by the use of auto. Never use auto in (embedded) systems. Swap it out for uint32_t.

@TomV it is spinning in the loop.

@Clifford I have set the flash latency to max in the following line
setBits(FLASH->ACR, FLASH_ACR_ICEN | FLASH_ACR_DCEN | FLASH_ACR_PRFTEN | FLASH_ACR_LATENCY, FLASH_ACR_ICEN | FLASH_ACR_DCEN | FLASH_ACR_PRFTEN | FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_7WS);
I first clear FLASH_ACR_LATENCY bits, then fill them with FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_7WS

@Lundin I saw that setting the latency to maximum seemed to help other people, so I did it in hopes of fixing the problem.

Is this is a Nucleo board?  If so does it really have a crystal?  It it just has a clock provided from the onboard debugger then you need to set the HSEBYP bit.

Can you show the full value of the CFGR and CR registers please?

@TomV
forgot to mention, my board is a black pill one and it comes with an on board 25 MHz crystal oscillator. Again, when I try to set the clocks in the Cube IDE, everything works as expected (25MHz HSE is selected as the PLL source, and the PLL as the system clock)

(I also don't like the macros from a style point of view, but I can't see anything wrong with them that would cause this behaviour in this code)

After that I guess you've just got to go through the generated Cube code line by line and modify your code until they make the exact same register writes.

That isn't what I asked, I am suggesting you improve the question by including the pertinent information in the question ( not in a comment).  When you set the latency is important, and you have not provided that information.

@Clifford you can see that the fhMspInit() function which sets the flash latency is getting called after power initialization and before HSE, PLL and system clock init code in the fhInit() function.
{
    setBits(FLASH->ACR, FLASH_ACR_ICEN | FLASH_ACR_DCEN | FLASH_ACR_PRFTEN | FLASH_ACR_LATENCY, FLASH_ACR_ICEN | FLASH_ACR_DCEN | FLASH_ACR_PRFTEN | FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_7WS);
}```

Understood.  Although viewing on a phone, I didn't spot that due to line length.  Moreover the function name (presumably after Cube's MCU Support Package https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37514022/what-does-the-msp-in-stm32cubemx-hal-xxx-mspinit-functions-stand-for) is somewhat obscure.  FlashInit() perhaps would make that clearer since that is all it does.

Fixed it. Turns out I was using setBits when I should have used writeBits:
setBits does not set the register value directly, it only touches the bits provided by the mask. I should have instead used writeBits, which is equivalent to X = Y, instead of setBits's X = (X & ~M) | Y.
#define setBits(x, msk, v) x = ((x) & ~((u32)(msk))) | (u32)(v)
#define setMask(x, msk) x |= msk
#define writeBits(x, v) x = (u32)v
#define clearBits(x, msk) x = ((x) & ~(u32)(msk))

void fhHseInit()
{
    setBits(RCC->CR, RCC_CR_HSEON, RCC_CR_HSEON);
    halt((RCC->CR & RCC_CR_HSERDY) == 0);
}

void fhPllDisable()
{
    setBits(RCC->CR, RCC_CR_PLLON, 0);
    halt(RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLLRDY);
}

void fhPllEnable()
{
    setBits(RCC->CR, RCC_CR_PLLON, RCC_CR_PLLON);
    halt((RCC->CR & RCC_CR_PLLRDY) == 0);
}

#define HSE_VALUE 25000000

void fhUpdateCoreClock()
{
    u32 pllm        = RCC->PLLCFGR & RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM;
    u32 pllvco      = (uint64_t)HSE_VALUE * (uint64_t)((RCC->PLLCFGR & RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN) >> RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN_Pos) / (uint64_t)pllm;
    u32 pllp        = (((RCC->PLLCFGR & RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLP) >> RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLP_Pos) + 1U) * 2U;
    u32 sysCfkFreq  = pllvco / pllp;
    SystemCoreClock = sysCfkFreq >> AHBPrescTable[(RCC->CFGR & RCC_CFGR_HPRE) >> RCC_CFGR_HPRE_Pos];
}

void fhPllInit()
{
    fhPllDisable();

    u8 m = 25;
    u8 n = 192;
    u8 p = 2;
    u8 q = 4;

    u32 pllReg = RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLSRC_HSE;
    pllReg |= m << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLM_Pos;
    pllReg |= n << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLN_Pos;
    pllReg |= ((p >> 1) - 1) << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLP_Pos;
    pllReg |= q << RCC_PLLCFGR_PLLQ_Pos;

    writeBits(RCC->PLLCFGR, pllReg);

    fhPllEnable();
}

void fhCpuInit()
{
    u32 latency = FLASH_ACR_LATENCY_3WS;

    if (latency > fhFlashGetLatency())
    {
        setBits(FLASH->ACR, FLASH_ACR_LATENCY, latency);
    }

    setBits(RCC->CFGR, RCC_CFGR_PPRE1, RCC_CFGR_PPRE1_DIV16);
    setBits(RCC->CFGR, RCC_CFGR_PPRE2, RCC_CFGR_PPRE2_DIV16);
    setBits(RCC->CFGR, RCC_CFGR_HPRE, RCC_CFGR_HPRE_DIV1);

    setBits(RCC->CFGR, RCC_CFGR_SW, RCC_CFGR_SW_PLL);
    halt((RCC->CFGR & RCC_CFGR_SWS) != RCC_CFGR_SWS_PLL);

    setBits(RCC->CFGR, RCC_CFGR_PPRE1, RCC_CFGR_PPRE1_DIV2);
    setBits(RCC->CFGR, RCC_CFGR_PPRE2, RCC_CFGR_PPRE2_DIV2); // APB2 clock = 96 MHz / 2 = 48 MHz (max for sd card is 25MHz, lowest prescaler is DIV2, so the maximum frequency is 24MHz, the lowest is 187.5khZ)

    fhUpdateCoreClock();

    if (latency < fhFlashGetLatency())
    {
        setBits(FLASH->ACR, FLASH_ACR_LATENCY, latency);
    }
}

void fhInitMsp()
{
    setBits(RCC->APB2ENR, RCC_APB2ENR_SYSCFGEN, RCC_APB2ENR_SYSCFGEN);
    setBits(RCC->APB1ENR, RCC_APB1ENR_PWREN, RCC_APB1ENR_PWREN);
    setBits(PWR->CR, PWR_CR_VOS, PWR_CR_VOS);
}

void fhInit()
{
    fhFlashInit();
    fhInitMsp();
    fhHseInit();
    fhPllInit();
    fhCpuInit();

    systickInit();
}

